# Bootstrap disabling radio btn-group with data-toggle=buttons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.3.6 and I am trying to disable this type of radio btn-group. I've tried placing the disabled on both the label and input, but it doesn't seem to work. The buttons would appear as disabled but still clickable. Whenever I click the buttons, an active class will be added.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"> 
 <label class="btn btn-default disabled">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="0" disabled="disabled">NO 
 </label>

 <label class="btn btn-default disabled">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="1" disabled="disabled">YES
 </label>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to disable the buttons?

Answer (score 4):

For demo find below link of jsfiddle

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary disabled">
    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Radio 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary active disabled">
    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary disabled">
    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/k6a3j46o/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` attribute on the input will disable it, as in, you cannot change the value of the input while it's disabled. What you're seeing are the CSS stypes added by bootstrap that make it sorta look like something changed when you remove your mouse from the input.

You can prevent these styles with a little bit of jQuery:

```js
$(".btn.disabled").mouseout(function(){ 
  $(this).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"> 
 <label class="btn btn-default disabled">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="0" disabled>NO 
 </label>

 <label class="btn btn-default disabled">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="1" disabled>YES
 </label>
</div>
```